# WORDPRESS: Trying to edit News.php (Page Template) but nothing changes in browser

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, position, footer

The footer on my news page is inside of the container.

The actual file has the footer code outside of the container, 
so I can't really grasp what is causing the footer to move positions.

I tried to edit my `news.php` but when I edit (delete certain `divs` on that template) nothing changes. However, if I delete `divs` within my `index.php` file there are changes when I view the site in my browser.

Why might this be happening?

The HTML is pretty much the same in each file so I don't get it.

Take a look at these pages to see the difference.

- http://keihead.com/test/about - Correct
- http://keihead.com/test/news - Wrong

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress specific page templates get's loaded based on the query. Check out [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) from WordPress codex.

I think you are editing the wrong file. Find out which template is getting called and change that particular file.